# add data in DataTable for each button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i have a form of data. each save button click ,I need to change in DataTable.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("1"), new DataColumn("2"), new DataColumn("3")});
        dt.Rows.Add( 1.Text, 2.Text, 3.Text);
}
```

currently last button click data only storing in data table .
how can I store all the  button save data to this data table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is good way
but work :

```
    public static DataTable dt = new DataTable() { Columns = { new DataColumn("1"), new DataColumn("2"), new DataColumn("3") } };
    protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "1", "1");
        var count = dt.Rows.Count;
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: still only last added row in dt.rows bro .

Comment: @xyz Updated my Answer and add Result